# Does anyone have any example code or recommended plug ins for adding the rel=prev and rel=next tags for paginationN

Tags: template, seo, code

Does anyone have any example code they have used in magento to implement the rel=prev and rel=next tags for paginated content on a magento site?

or if you have a recommended plug in?

Answer (score 2):

Jay, you can achieve that easily without using plug in:

1. Copy `page/html/pager.html` from `base/default` theme into your design theme
2. Open file using editor
3. Look for anchor tag with "previous" class and add `rel="prev"` there
4. Look for anchor tag with "next" class and add `rel="next"` there

Comment: thank you for your response but i do think there is some additional code that needs to be addeed in the header..

Answer (score 2):

For implementation as per [Google's documentation](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html):-

Insert the below into your themes `head.phtml`:-

```
<?php
$actionName = $this->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if ($actionName == 'catalog_category_view') // Category Page
{
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $prodCol = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)));
    $tool = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager')->setLimit($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getLimit())->setCollection($prodCol);
    $linkPrev = false;
    $linkNext = false;
    if ($tool->getCollection()->getSelectCountSql()) {
        if ($tool->getLastPageNum() > 1) {
            if (!$tool->isFirstPage()) {
                $linkPrev = true;
                if ($tool->getCurrentPage() == 2) {
                    $url = explode('?', $tool->getPreviousPageUrl());
                    $prevUrl = @$url[0];
                }
                else {
                    $prevUrl = $tool->getPreviousPageUrl();
                }
            }
            if (!$tool->isLastPage()) {
                $linkNext = true;
                $nextUrl = $tool->getNextPageUrl();
            }
        }
    }
    if ($linkPrev) echo '<link rel="prev" href="' . $prevUrl . '" />';
    if ($linkNext) echo '<link rel="next" href="' . $nextUrl . '" />';
}
?>
```

I recently [published](http://www.ukbusinessforums.co.uk/threads/magento-google-help.334341/#post-2480391) this on a forum that discusses this in Magento. Originally sourced from [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-implement-relprev-and-relnext-to-magentos-pagination/). Tested and confirmed working in Magento 1.9.